# Should I remove the watermarks of my images before training Yolov8?

Tags: computer-vision, image-preprocessing, yolo, yolov8

I would like to train a Yolov8 network in an animal detection task using camera trap images. Some camera trap images have information added to them such as date, time, day of the week, camera brand, etc. Should I remove this information from the image, i.e. with a black square, before training my Yolo, or it doesn't matter.